# duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with androidx

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I already checked all the similar questions but no luck at finding a solution.

A problem occurred after migrating my libs to androidx.

```
 error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_anchorGravity' with config ''.
 error: resource previously defined here.
```

**Here is my Gradle file:**

```
dependencies {
playerReleaseImplementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
playerDebugImplementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libsDebug')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
//Dagger 2 dependencies
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.percentlayout:percentlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'

def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"

def room_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'

// Other
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.16"
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta3'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.6'
implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:library:1.8.1@aar'
implementation 'uk.co.ribot:easyadapter:1.5.0@aar'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.8'
implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.karumi:headerrecyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.TouchBoarder:weekdays-buttons-bar:v1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:1.1.1'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
debugImplementation('com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.4.2') {
    transitive = false;
}
implementation 'de.cketti.mailto:email-intent-builder:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.3'

debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
```

}

My compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion is 28

**I've already:**

1. checked if there are conflicting libs
2. cleaned - invalidate cache on the android studio

I think there are no conflicting libs. I've already cleaned-invalids cache etc. on the android studio.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the jetifier enabled? If not, some of the other libraries may depend on original support library artifacts. Both AndroidX and the support library define the same attrs, hence the conflict.

Comment: No I don't use Jetifier anywhere in my project, also I've made sure I deleted all support libraries. Only AndroidX libraries are being used.

Comment: So you don't have any other dependencies apart from androidx mentioned above?

Comment: All other dependencies are third party. Will add them too.

Comment: Good, these third party dependencies themselves may depend on old support library. That's why you'll want to enable jetifier - to make them switch to androidx at build time. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try, thank you

Comment: Some of your other dependencies look ancient, you should probably postpone AndroidX for the moment. **First make sure your project works correctly with support library 28.0.0.** That's feature equivalent of AndroidX 1.0.0. Only then migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: yep, I'll update butterknife and dagger first. Thank you